# Tracking a single Android phone through a google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hey guys i am gonna work on a Android collage project in which (our sir explained) we have to track a single Android phone on google maps by the mobile's id and then be able to send messages and voice chat. The chatting system is other thing i just want to know how to do the tracking part any easy way or something to help me out thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like Firebase. You can register the mobile's id in a firebase graph as key and the other informations under that key, as latitude, longitude,...

[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

Comment: so the fire base gonna calculate all the things but i want to make a app in which the google map track the specific one mobile and thenthe user can start chatting with him/her

Comment: yes you can do that uploading mobile target informations to firebase and loading those informations to show all on map. So target send informations and other mobiles load target informations from the same firebase table.

Comment: the same thing for chat and messages, you can do a sub key of mobile's id target, like 'messages' and store messages under that. With firebase you have event listeners, so when there is an update, all registered listeners will be notified